# MigraDoc image not found

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have a script lets say in folder 'root'. I have a folder inside root called 'Images', and inside images an image called 'logo.png'.

- **root**

  - script.cs
  - **Images**

    - logo.png

I have the following code to create a section:

```
Document document = new Document();

Section section = document.AddSection();
```

And I have tried this:

```
section.AddImage("../../Images/logo.png");
```

and this:

```
section.AddImage("Images/logo.png");
```

to try and add an image, but both return 'image not found'.

I've already tried updating MigraDoc to v1.5 but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "script" gets compiled and you get an assembly that is executed. You are using relative paths and by default the image will be searched relative to the working directory of the process which most likely is relative to the folder with the assembly. With ASP.NET things can be even more complicated.

Tip: The `DocumentRenderer` class has a `WorkingDirectory` property. If you set it then images with relative paths will be searched relative to this working directory. Set it to "root" and the second path "Images/logo.png" should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Lets say my real directory is 'Application/Project.csproj/Images/logo.png', what would the exact code be to set as the working directory?

Comment: If your assembly is in 'Application/Project.csproj/bin/debug' then "../../Images/logo.png" should do the trick. Another "../" may be needed - e.g. if your assembly is in "bin/debug/net462" or a similar folder. And this only applies if you do not set a working folder for your project.

Comment: Maybe include `section.AddParagraph(Environment.CurrentDirectory);` to find out where you are starting from.

Comment: Forgive me, I am new to the concept of class libraries and such, but this project has 4 main folders (one of which is 'Application'), and each holds about 20 class libraries ('project.csproj' being one of them). I know the 'main' project is in a root folder called 'Presentation', but don't understand assemblies enough to know what gets assembled where... The @"../../Image/logo.png' didn't work either sadly. With environment.currentdirectory I got some local folder similar to 'C:/Implementation/release' whereas the solution itself is in 'C:/Implementation/source'.

Comment: I got it working with 'var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"LogoFolder/Logo.png");' and then 'section.AddImage(dir.FullName)'. However, I somewhat cheated. I checked the 'Implementation/Release' folder and found that there was a folder already in there called 'LogoFolder/Logo.png', which had the logo I needed, therefore I referenced that. But thanks for the help, you no doubt  nudged me in the right direction. Would've liked to spend a bit more time getting it working exactly how I wanted it to though. Maybe I'll look into that sometime soon to solve this fully.

Comment: Then the relative path would be like "../source/Project.csproj/Images/logo.png". For deployment it will probably cause problems to link from the Release folder to the Source folder. The files you need should be in the folder that gets deployed, so your solution could be correct or at least on the right track.

Comment: Ahh yes! That is correct. I just added the following: 'section.AddImage(@"../Source/Application/Project/Images/logo.png");'. Now it works as intended; no cheating ;) - Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW: The "@" is only needed if you use the backslash '\' in the path, it has no effect when you use the forward slash '/' as you do. That was my lapse and I removed it a few seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me because I realize the age of this thread before providing an answer, but I too had the same issue that the accepted answer was unable to resolve.

In C# you are able to use [HostingEnvironment.MapPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath?view=netframework-4.8) to reference relative paths. In your case, it'd look like:

```
section.AddImage(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/logo.png"));
```

Comment: Apologies, but I don't have the code to test this anymore - so I'm unable to mark it as accepted since I can't verify it! But thanks for posting an answer :)

Comment: @AidanH, not a biggie. I wanted it more for visibility because your question comes up as one of the top search results on Google when searching this issue.